# Prove that $(M/IM)\otimes_{R/I} (N/IN) \cong (M \otimes_{R} N)/ I(M \otimes_{R} N)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

> Show that  $(M/IM)\otimes_{R/I} (N/IN) \cong (M \otimes_{R} N)/ I(M \otimes_{R} N)$

I tried to define a map $\phi : (M/IM)\times (N/IN) \to (M \otimes_{R} N)/ I(M \otimes_{R} N)$ by, $(\bar{m},\bar{n}) \mapsto \bar{(m\otimes n)} $, but not quite sure whether it's even well-defined!

Help will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use $M/IM=M \otimes_R R/I$. Ask again if necessary.